# For each line in command output add to array

Tags: arrays, bash, pipe, heredoc

I am trying to do the following in a bash script: add all the device node files which don't start with `/dev/sda` to an array called `devices`. As the script will be executed on a read-only filesystem, I ***cannot*** use here documents.

Here is my code:

```
devices=()
ls -1 /dev/hd* /dev/sd* | while read -r device; do
    if [[ "$device" != "/dev/sda"* ]]; then
        devices+=($device)
    fi
done
```

I don't understand why, at the end of the commands, `devices` is still empty. For example, I can successfully print each item just by adding the command `echo $device` before/after adding it to the array. But why don't they get added?

Also, if I run the same commands using here documents everything works fine:

```
devices=()
while read -r device; do
    if [[ "$device" != "/dev/sda"* ]]; then
        devices+=($device)
    fi
done <<< $(ls -1 /dev/hd* /dev/sd*)
```

At the end of these commands the array `devices` is correctly filled.

Can you help me understand why the first code extract doesn't work while the second one does? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I solved my problem by using bash Process Substitution:

```
devices=()
while read -r device; do
    if [[ "$device" != "/dev/sda"* ]]; then
        devices+=($device)
    fi
done < <(ls -1 /dev/hd* /dev/sd*)
```

This way it works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `ls`, `read`, or process substitution. Just use a `for` loop.

```
devices=( /dev/hd* )
for device in /dev/sd*; do
    [[ $device != /dev/sda* ]] && devices+=("$device")
done
```

In fact, with extended patterns, you don't even need a loop.

```
shopt -s extglob
devices=( /dev/hd* /dev/sd!(a)* )
```